# SQL (BigQuery) - get rows with a specific value and add count when a sequence of that value is broken with another value by group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grouping

Say I have the following dataset

```
'2022-01-01' - A - a
'2022-01-02' - A - a
'2022-01-03' - A - b
'2022-01-03' - A - a
'2022-01-01' - B - a
'2022-01-01' - B - b
'2022-01-02' - B - c
'2022-01-02' - B - a
'2022-01-03' - B - b
'2022-01-01' - C - a
'2022-01-02' - C - a
'2022-01-03' - C - a
'2022-01-01' - C - c
'2022-01-02' - C - a
'2022-01-03' - C - a
'2022-01-04' - C - b
'2022-01-05' - C - a
```

the query I am currently looking for would arrive at this dataset:

```
A - a - 1
A - a - 1
A - a - 2
B - a - 1
B - a - 2
C - a - 1
C - a - 1
C - a - 1
C - a - 2
C - a - 2
C - a - 3
```

essentially eliminating all rows that don't have value 'a' in the third column and and adding a counter whenever the sequence of a's is broken and resumed within the grouping in column 2. how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

An approach using window functions:

```sql
with sample as (
  select '2022-01-01' as date, 'A' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-02' as date, 'A' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-03' as date, 'A' as l1, 'b' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-03' as date, 'A' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-01' as date, 'B' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-01' as date, 'B' as l1, 'b' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-02' as date, 'B' as l1, 'c' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-02' as date, 'B' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-03' as date, 'B' as l1, 'b' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-01' as date, 'C' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-02' as date, 'C' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-03' as date, 'C' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-01' as date, 'C' as l1, 'c' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-02' as date, 'C' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-03' as date, 'C' as l1, 'a' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-04' as date, 'C' as l1, 'b' as l2 UNION ALL
  select '2022-01-05' as date, 'C' as l1, 'a' as l2
),
number_rows AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as row_number -- ideally you would have a column to order the rows
  FROM sample
),
flag_changes AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    IF((row_number - LAG(row_number) OVER (PARTITION BY l1 ORDER BY row_number ASC)) != 1, 1, 0) as changed
  FROM number_rows
  WHERE l2 = 'a'
)
SELECT 
  * EXCEPT (row_number, changed),
  1 + SUM(changed) OVER (PARTITION BY l1 ORDER BY row_number ASC)
FROM flag_changes
```

Output:

```
l1  l2  counter
A   a   1
A   a   1
A   a   2
B   a   1
B   a   2
C   a   1
C   a   1
C   a   1
C   a   2
C   a   2
C   a   3
```

NOTE: This solution depends on a way to order and number the rows in the same way you put in the sample data. On the sample I used `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()`, but if you use this in a large table, you could have different results on each run.